# Syntax error for my javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

Listed below is my html form for a calculator.

```js
function calc() {
  var a = parseInt(document.querySelector(#value1).value);
  var b = parseInt(document.querySelector(#value2).value);
  var op = document.querySelector(#operator).value;
  var Calculate;
  if (op == "add") {
    Calculate = a + b;
  } else if (op == "min") {
    Calculate = a - b;
  } else if (op == "div") {
    Calculate = a / b;
  } else if (op == "min") {
    Calculate = a * b;
  }
  document.querySelector(#results).innerhtml = calculate
}
```

```html
<form>
  value 1: <input type="text" id="value1"> value 2: <input type="text" id="value2"> Operator:
  <select id="operator">
    <option value="add">Add</option>
    <option value="min">Subtract</option>
    <option value="div">Divide</option>
    <option value="mul">Multiply</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
</form>
<div id=#results></div>
```

And I receive a syntax error here ;

```
var a = parseInt(document.querySelector(#value1).value);
```

Comment: Use quotes around `#results` and `#value1` etc

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with this code.

#### Syntax Error

The first (and what the error is reporting) is [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) expects a String as its argument. To fix this, you just need to put quotes (`'`) around your selectors.

So anywhere you have something like this:

```
 document.querySelector(#results);
```

It instead should be

```
 document.querySelector('#results');
```

#### Correct attribute to set `innerHTML`

Additionally, the correct attribute to set HTML on an element is [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) (not `innerhtml`).

#### ReferenceError: `calculate` is not defined

JavaScript is [case-sensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types), so when you defined `var Calculate;` above and try to reference with `calculate` (lower case `c`), you'll get an error. This was probably just a typo, so you just need to use `Calculate` (capital `C`).

#### Bad ID value

In your HTML, you have your *results* div set as `<div id="#results"></div>`. You probably didn't want to include the hash sign (`#`) in the ID itself. That is used when leveraging an [ID selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors).

If you did keep the hash sign as an actual part of the ID, you'd need to escape it in your JavaScript with something like `document.querySelector('#\\#results')` which is probably not what you want.

Instead, just change the HTML to remove the hash from the actual ID value:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

#### Missing logic for `mul` operator

Your JavaScript has a bug: you reference `if (op == 'min')` twice. The last conditional should probably read `if (op == 'mul')` if you want the code to execute correctly.

### Entire Solution

After applying all the fixes above, your final code should look like:

```js
function calc() {
  var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);
  var op = document.querySelector("#operator").value;
  var Calculate;

  if (op == "add") {
    Calculate = a + b;
  } else if (op == "min") {
    Calculate = a - b;
  } else if (op == "div") {
    Calculate = a / b;
  } else if (op == "mul") {
    Calculate = a * b;
  }

  document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML = Calculate;
}
```

```html
<form>
  value 1: <input type="text" id="value1">
  value 2: <input type="text" id="value2">
  Operator:
  <select id="operator">
    <option value="add">Add</option>
    <option value="min">Subtract</option>
    <option value="div">Divide</option>
    <option value="mul">Multiply</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: `op` can never equal `"min"` and `calculate` is undefined.

Comment: Turns out there were several problems with the code! I fixed all of them up with explanations for each issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thry this. You have to use quotes as below.

```
function calc() {
var a = parseInt(document.querySelector('#value1').value);
var b = parseInt(document.querySelector('#value2').value);
var op = document.querySelector('#operator').value;
var Calculate;
if(op=="add"){
 Calculate=a+b;
}
else if(op=="min"){
  Calculate=a-b;
}
else if(op=="div"){
  Calculate=a/b;
}
else if(op=="min"){
 Calculate=a*b;
} 

document.querySelector('#results').innerhtml=calculate
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy I'm still figuring out how i missed a " " there

Comment: This would still be incorrect as "calculate" is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the `id` when you are using `document.querySelector()`. Also make sure that your variable names are consistent. Remember that variable names are case-sensitive. For instance, you name a variable `Calculate`, but tried it call it using `calculate` which is undefined. You should also never have special characters in `id`s or `class`es like `#` (for `id`) and `.` (for `class`) unless you escape them with a backslash (`\`) or double backslash (`\\`). You should not have a `div` with `id` `#results`, just make its `id` `results`.

```html
<form>
  value 1: <input type="text" id="value1"> value 2: <input type="text" id="value2"> Operator:
  <select id="operator">
    <option value="add">Add</option>
    <option value="min">Subtract</option>
    <option value="div">Divide</option>
    <option value="mul">Multiply</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
<script>
function calc() {
  var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);
  var op = document.querySelector("#operator").value;
  var Calculate;
  if(!document.querySelector("#value1").value.trim().length||!document.querySelector("#value2").value.trim().length){
  document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML = "<b style='color: red;'>You must enter both operands!</b>"
  } else {
  if (op == "add") {
    Calculate = a + b;
  } else if (op == "min") {
    Calculate = a - b;
  } else if (op == "div") {
    Calculate = a / b;
  } else if (op == "mul") {//should be "mul", not "min" which is undefined
    Calculate = a * b;
  }
  document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML = Calculate;//you must capitalize 'Calculate' or it is undefined
 }
}
document.querySelector('#value2').addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
  if(event.keyCode==13){//calculate when Enter is pressed in input#value2
   calc();
  }
});
</script>
```